# black berry web works

Tags: blackberry

i am using webworks tool for devolepping a web application in blackberry... the jquery  command $.getJSON is not working in it .. please help me by giving a good solution for that

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? How is it not behaving the way you think it should?

Answer (score 0):

Check the BlackBerry Support Community Forums, I think [PlayBook Webworks cannot read local files](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/PlayBook-Webworks-cannot-read-local-files/m-p/812209/highlight/true#M9789) will help.